# ArgumentException : "the path is not of a legal form" when using the CallerFilePath attribute in a script

Tags: c#, roslyn

## Context

I am trying to run a C# script (.csx file) programmatically from a program I will call `ScriptRunner.exe` here and that I wrote myself (because `csi.exe` doesn't output what I want).`ScriptRunner.exe` is a simple console application and its most interesting feature is to have the following line :

```
var state = await CSharpScript.RunAsync<int>(script, referencesAndUsings, globalArgs);
```

`ScriptRunner.exe` works great ! However...

## Problem

The moment my script contains **the following line** :

```
static string GetCurrentFileName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string fileName = null) { return fileName; }
```

and in particular `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath]`, I get an **ArgumentException : "the path is not of a legal form"** ; note that the latter doesn't appear if I use the same line from a C# Interactive through a `#load` command - which correctly shows the path of my .csx file.

## Investigated elements until now

- The stacktrace shows `at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)`

  - I checked what seems to be the [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/87ad0e97413def13.html)

    - I checked by hand the path of my csx file ; there's no invalid path characters in the path to my csx, and no wildcards in it either.
- I checked there was no reference issue with `mscorlib`
- Maybe something is missing in the [ScriptOptions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Scripting/Core/ScriptOptions.cs) (`referencesAndUsings` in my first sample code), I looked at it but... I don't seem to understand everything well enough

  - The way I created my `ScriptOptions` ("`referencesAndUsings`") looks like the following:

  `var myOptions = ScriptOptions.Default;
  myOptions.AddReferences(new List<string>() { ... });
  myOptions.AddImports(new List<string>() { ... });`
- [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is the documentation for the `CallerFilePath` attribute
- [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh534540(v=vs.110)) is the documentaiont for the concept of Caller Information

What really saddens me is that it *works* in C# Interactive.

## Question

Does anyone know why it wouldn't want to work when interpreted by my `ScriptRunner.exe` ; and how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
var state = await CSharpScript.RunAsync<int>(script, referencesAndUsings, globalArgs);
```

`script` is the script itself (the contents of the csx file). As such it has no path. CSharpScript knows nothing about the path of your csx file. When you call `GetCurrentFileName` from within the script, there is no path information.

You need to specify a `FilePath` in `ScriptOptions` using `WithFilePath(csxFilePath)`

Comment: Thank you so much !